# How to fix null error in getWidth() on bitmap

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, compression, android-bitmap

In my application i want to select image from **gallery** and **compress** it.
For compress i use this library : https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor

I wrote below codes for it, but when i run the application and select image from gallery, it throws **force close**  and show below errors in **logCat** :

**My activity codes :**

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO) {
                if (data != null) {
                    // Get the Image from data
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    assert cursor != null;
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    postPath = mediaPath;
                    uploadImageToServer(postPath);
                }

            }
        } else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        }
    }
}
    private void uploadImageToServer(String imagePath) {
        if (imagePath == null || imagePath.equals("")) {
            return;
        } else {
            showpDialog();
            Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
            File file = new File(imagePath);
            try {
                compressedImage = new Compressor(getActivity())
                        .setMaxWidth(2000)
                        .setMaxHeight(1400)
                        .setQuality(90)
                        .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
                        .setDestinationDirectoryPath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath())
                        .compressToFile(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

**LogCat error :**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at id.zelory.compressor.ImageUtil.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(ImageUtil.java:70)
                                                                       at id.zelory.compressor.ImageUtil.compressImage(ImageUtil.java:33)
                                                                       at id.zelory.compressor.Compressor.compressToFile(Compressor.java:60)
                                                                       at id.zelory.compressor.Compressor.compressToFile(Compressor.java:56)
                                                                       at com.app.android.Fragments.NewAddressFragment.uploadImageToServer(NewAddressFragment.java:486)
                                                                       at com.app.android.Fragments.NewAddressFragment.onActivityResult(NewAddressFragment.java:353)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:156)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7295)
```

**Show error for this line :** `.compressToFile(file);`

**UPDATE :** show this error just for some images no all images!
How can i fix it? please help me

Comment: This is because your generated Bitmap is null.

Comment: @VirRajpurohit, show this error just for some images no all images! how can i fix it? can you help me?

Comment: check which variable is null, and either instantiate it, or abort the process

Comment: That some images needs to be identified as there can problem with URI.

Comment: @Stultuske, can you send to me for how can i it? please

Comment: @VirRajpurohit, how can i it? can you send to me for how can i it? please

Comment: your `imagePath` likely does not point to the image file, or you have no access to it.

Comment: @Hock you don't know how to test for null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another assumption on [GitHub](http://%20github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor/issues/49) is, that you probably try to store the changed file with the original name in the original path. This also may lead to problems. Please try this version of code. I added `compressedFileName`.

```
private void uploadImageToServer(String imagePath) {
        if (imagePath == null || imagePath.equals("")) {
            return;
        } else {
            showpDialog();
            Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
            File file = new File(imagePath);

            if(file != null && file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
                try {
                    String compressedFileName = "_" + file.getName();

                    compressedImage = new Compressor(getActivity())
                            .setMaxWidth(2000)
                            .setMaxHeight(1400)
                            .setQuality(90)
                            .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
                            .setDestinationDirectoryPath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath())
                            .compressToFile(file, compressedFileName);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the new filename gets an additional underscore. `compressedFileName = "_" + file.getName();`.

Comment: it/s very bad! again show error! whyyyyyyyy? :( :(

Comment: Sorry, but then I have no further idea. android itself is not my cup of tea...

Comment: very thanks for your helps and times , thanks dear

Answer (score 1):

Please handle through try and catch block and show dialog message to user for select another image, may be selected image is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that file is not null.

```
private void uploadImageToServer(String imagePath) {
        if (imagePath == null || imagePath.equals("")) {
            return;
        } else {
            showpDialog();
            Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
            File file = new File(imagePath);

            if(file != null && file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
                try {
                    compressedImage = new Compressor(getActivity())
                            .setMaxWidth(2000)
                            .setMaxHeight(1400)
                            .setQuality(90)
                            .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
                            .setDestinationDirectoryPath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath())
                            .compressToFile(file);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: again show me error :(

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This was still only a path check. I just extended the if-clause. It now checks whether the file itself exists. Please try again.

Comment: not work again! why show me error! i'm bad lucky

Comment: Still the same error? Or some other kind of error?

Comment: show above error again!

Comment: Okay, maybe it really has to do with the accessibility of the file. I extended the if-clause again. It now checks additionally `file.canRead()`. This should be sufficient for your needs. There are also `file.canWrite()` and `file.canExecute()` but I reckon you won't neither write into the file nor execute it. ;) -- try again, please.

Comment: not work again :( . can you see this link : https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor/issues/49 please see this link and help me. please :(

Comment: can you help me my bro? please. i really need your help. please

Comment: are you here my bro? :(

Comment: I posted another answer. Give it a try.